# Named route for added action is not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, custom-routes

Ok, I need help with this one.  I have defined a resource with non-standard actions.  It looks like this in `config/routes.rb`:

```rb
1 Upload::Application.routes.draw do
2
3   resources :lib_imports, :only => [:index, :new, :create, :show] do
4     get 'reimport', :on => :member
5   end
  ...
```

I can see the routes I expect when I run `rails routes`

```
$ rake routes
reimport_lib_import GET    /lib_imports/:id/reimport(.:format) {:action=>"reimport", :controller=>"lib_imports"}
        lib_imports GET    /lib_imports(.:format)              {:action=>"index", :controller=>"lib_imports"}
     new_lib_import GET    /lib_imports/new(.:format)          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"lib_imports"}
    edit_lib_import GET    /lib_imports/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"lib_imports"}
         lib_import GET    /lib_imports/:id(.:format)          {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lib_imports"}
...
```

I'm trying to use the named route "reimport_lib_import" in the index view for the LibImport model, `index.html.erb`, part of which looks like this:

```html
...
10 <% @lib_imports.each do |lib_import| %>
11   <tr>
12     <td><%= lib_import.spreadsheet %></td>
13     <td><%= link_to 'Show', lib_import %></td>
14     <td><%= link_to 'Re-import', reimport_lib_import %></td>
15   </tr>
16 <% end %>
...
```

However, the result is that the browser displays an error.  The relevant part of the error is:

```
Showing /home/mike/rails_projects/experiments/upload/app/views/lib_imports/index.html.erb where line #14 raised:

undefined local variable or method `reimport_lib_import' for #<#<Class:0x007fa938a06778>:0x007fa938950720>

Extracted source (around line #14):

11:   <tr>
12:     <td><%= lib_import.spreadsheet %></td>
13:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', lib_import %></td>
14:     <td><%= link_to 'Re-import', reimport_lib_import %></td>
15:   </tr>
16: <% end %>
17: </table>
```

My the question is this: why does Rails complain about `reimport_lib_import` when I try to use it?  The fact that it sails by `lib_import` on the previous line without complaint but trips over this one has me quite puzzled  Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Does using `reimport_lib_import_url` instead of `reimport_lib_import` change anything? I'm a little rusty with Rails 2.

Comment: reimport_lib_import_url or reimport_lib_import_path should work. Let me know if you get error again.

Comment: Devin and Bhushan, you are both right.  Thanks for the comments.  Devin I'm using Rails 3, but am curious: what was it in my question that made you think it was Rails 2?  Am I doing something that is obsolete in Rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', lib_import_path(lib_import) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Re-import', reimport_lib_import_path(lib_import) %></td>
```

The names generated (shown) in the `rake routes` need to be followed by `_path` for a relative path, or `_url` for a full url.
Secondly, if it is a member path, you need to specify the member, in this case: `lib_import` itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that was it.  Thanks for helping out a newbie.